# MessageBox.Show() Not showing on top of ShowDialog form

Tags: c#, winforms, showmodaldialog

I have the following code which displays a form as ShowDialog().

```
static void Main()
{

    DialogResult oDialogResult = oLogin.ShowDialog();

    if (oDialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       try
       {
           //do something here
       }
       catch (Exception Ex)
       {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, "IMPORTANT MESSAGE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
       }
   }
}
```

The problem is the call MessageBox.Show is not showing the message box in front of (on top of) the already showing oLogin.ShowDialog() form. Do you know why ?

I tried changing the MessageBox.Show to include the owner form as is the following;

```
MessageBox.Show(oLogin, Ex.Message, "IMPORTANT MESSAGE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

But still have the same problem.

Comment: Kinda obvious.  You could have oLogin fire an event just before it assigns the DialogResult property.  An event of type CancelEventHandler would be the logical choice so you can also stop the dialog from closing.  Compare to the OpenFileDialog.FileOk event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code in your Main() method to what the visual studio project template originally created:-

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles(); 
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
Application.Run(oLogin);
```

Then, add your try/catch block to a FormClosing event handler on whatever class is oLogin

Answer (score 0):

The code you've pasted doesn't do what you describe - by the time the MessageBox is shown, the other Dialog has already closed - so there is no Dialog to display in front of.

Paste your actual code or ask your question better.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem.  The other Dialog box has closed, but why ?

Comment: @Tommo1977 Because oLogin has code to close the form in response to some button click?

Comment: @Emi987 You are right, that is how it works.  So how can I get the MesageBox.Show to appear infront of a ShowDialog() ?

Comment: You can't. ShowDialog(), by design, shows a *modal* dialog, which blocks execution of that thread until the dialog closes.

Comment: what you actually want to do is documented below.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
DialogResult oDialogResult = oLogin.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: If I add 'this' I get this error. 'keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property static method or static field initializer'.  This part of the code above is in the static void Main() method of the application.

Comment: Sorry, I though it was inside a form.